# 'str' object does not support item assignment with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a dataframe and I am trying to add a column to the data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rnd

all_df = pd.read_csv('Cleaned-Data.csv')

for dataset in all_df:
    dataset['Severity'] = 1
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-d3aa149f309c> in <module>
      1 for dataset in all_df:
----> 2     dataset['Severity'] = 1

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I wanted to add a little more to the problem. I don't actually need one column add with only a single value added. I was trying to simplify the problem to try and understand what is wrong.

The modified code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rnd

all_df = pd.read_csv('Cleaned-Data.csv')

all_df['Severity'] = 0
```

When I add the severity column it works. But when I add some logic and loop through the dataset I get the error again.

```
for dataset in all_df:
    dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_None'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 1
    dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_Moderate'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 3
    dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_Mild'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 2
    dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_Severe'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 4
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-d5f5b9230b07> in <module>
      1 for dataset in all_df:
----> 2     dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_None'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 1
      3     dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_Moderate'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 3
      4     dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_Mild'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 2
      5     dataset.loc[dataset['Severity_Severe'] == 1, 'Severity'] = 4

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

result of the first 5 rows.

[image]
Why am I getting the above error?

Answer (score 0):

When using pandas you don't need to loop through each row. It does that automatically for you in an efficient manner.

To create the `Severity` column, you can grab the indexes for the different severity columns where it's set and assign the value to the row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rnd

all_df = pd.read_csv('Cleaned-Data.csv')

severity_none_index = all_df[all_df['Severity_None'] == 1].index
severity_moderate_index = all_df[all_df['Severity_Moderate'] == 1].index
severity_mild_index = all_df[all_df['Severity_Mild'] == 1].index
severity_severe_index = all_df[all_df['Severity_Severe'] == 1].index

all_df.loc[severity_none_index]['Severity'] = 1
all_df.loc[severity_moderate_index]['Severity'] = 2
all_df.loc[severity_mild_index]['Severity'] = 3
all_df.loc[severity_severe_index]['Severity'] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a column on a df you just need to assign a value. Per default this column will be assigned a serie with the value that you assigned repeated the number of times that the length of your rows. If you want to assign a value for a specific row and column then you use iloc or loc, but if it is a whole new column then you assign a list or a serie of the same length of rows or a single value that would be repeated. 
Something like that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed on the fact that when you are using

```
for dataset in all_df:
```

It loops over all the column names of the dataset 'Cleaned-Data.csv' stored in all_df and not on the dataset. And these names are 'str' objects i.e string objects. Hence, you encounter the error. To add a new column though, you can simply do

```
all_df['Severity']=1
```

after loading the file using pd.read_csv('Cleaned-Data.csv')

Answer (score 0):

```
for dataset in all_df:
```

This line loops through all the headers of the DataFrame.

To create a new column called "Severity" simply remove the for loop and just do

```
all_df["Severity"] = 1
```

This adds 1 to each row under the column Severity for you.

Answer (score 0):

In you for loop you have

```
for dataset in all_df:
```

This loops through each of the columns.  You need to loop through each of the rowd so that you can put different values for Severity for different rows. Your for loop should change to:

```
for dataset in all_df.index:
```

Try this.  If you can post some lines of your DataFrame that would help us understand more.